# FragmentManager contains fragment from viewpager after state loss

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

On state loss or screen rotation and when my boolean flag is true, I want to recreate my screen. However, the fragment manager still has the previous fragment attached and it gets loaded.

What can I do to get rid of that fragment?

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private String[] mData;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mData= new String[0];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("key", position);

    Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.length;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mData[position];
}

public void setData(String[] data) {
    mData= data;
}
}
```

Piece of code in Activity onCreate()

```
mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
mViewPagerAdapter.setData(data);
viewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Why you need to remove the fragments explicitly? You can just prepare the data and refresh the content.

Comment: I need to remove the old fragment when I don't have the data anymore. I am trying to re-instantiate the fragment after the operation to fetch updated data. Otherwise it would crash accessing a null object.

Comment: Just check the fragment to avoid crash when you finish fetching updated data, the activity will handle the fragments' lifecycle, you just need to ensure the fragments get the latest data when it is about to show(e.g. in onCreateView())

Answer (score 0):

You may override `instantiateItem`() to detect screen rotation like a Fragment can.

Code example:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return o == view;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                    container, false);
   return view;
}
```

**Note**: `instantiateItem`() occurs upon screen rotation. Activity does not detect that. The hint is that the class does not have onCreateView() like the fragment class.